# Prevent escaping brackets in URLs

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, url

Our image server allows us to pass url parameters that trigger certain image manipulation operations. For instance the url `https://www.example.com/i/example/10570250?layer0=[w=600&h=1000&bg=rgba(228,228,228,125)&cm=multi]` scales the image and applies a blending mode.

The problem is that as soon as feed that string into an URL object, for example with `URL(string: "https://www.example.com/i/example/10570250?layer0=[w=600&h=1000&bg=rgba(228,228,228,125)&cm=multi]")` the brackets get escaped and the image server stops applying the operations.

The url becomes: `https://www.example.com/i/example/10570250?layer0=%5Bw=600&h=1000&bg=rgba(228,228,228,125)&cm=multi%5D`

Can I prevent URL from escaping the brackets? Or ist there some other way of escaping the url, before feeding it to `URL(string:)`, that the image server might accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You´re not allowed to include `[ ]` in your URL. Consider changing your API call to make this work for you.

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6
>   [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal
>   within square brackets ("[" and "]").  This is the only place where
>   square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.  In
>   anticipation of future, as-yet-undefined IP literal address formats,
>   an implementation may use an optional version flag to indicate such a 
>   format explicitly rather than rely on heuristic determination.

[Reference](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

Comment: Thank you, it's always good to learn something about URLs. :) Problem is I don't have a choice as the software is not in our hands. But I'll forward the info and perhaps someone can help.

Comment: Upvoted. Will wait with accept for a bit, perhaps someone finds a workaround from the iOS world.. ;)